# How to get inbox sms in pdu format in android

Tags: android, sms, pdu

Can someone let me know if there is a way to get the inbox sms in pdu format?

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help

```
     Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
     for (Object pdu : pdus) {
     SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
}
```

Comment: Hi DjHacktor... Thanks for ur quick reply. I have some confusion whether the above code will get the inbox sms(already existing) in pdu format.

Comment: no it will not get sms you need to crawl using cursor to get sms from inbox or if you want to receive incoming sms then this is work in broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

```
 SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) mBundle.get("pdus");
            if(pdus != null){
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                Log.e(TAG, "pdus length : "+pdus.length);
                for(int k=0; k<msgs.length; k++){
                    msgs[k] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[k]);  
                    Log.e(TAG, "getDisplayMessageBody : "+msgs[k].getDisplayMessageBody());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getDisplayOriginatingAddress : "+msgs[k].getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getMessageBody : "+msgs[k].getMessageBody());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getOriginatingAddress : "+msgs[k].getOriginatingAddress());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getProtocolIdentifier : "+msgs[k].getProtocolIdentifier());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getStatus : "+msgs[k].getStatus());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getStatusOnIcc : "+msgs[k].getStatusOnIcc());
                    Log.e(TAG, "getStatusOnSim : "+msgs[k].getStatusOnSim());
                    String dateTime=getDate(msgs[k].getTimestampMillis());
                      messageTypeArray = messageTypeArray +  "Inbox" + splitKey;
                      messageDateArray = messageDateArray + dateTime.substring(0, 11) + splitKey;
                      messageTimeArray = messageTimeArray + dateTime.substring(11, dateTime.length()) + splitKey;
                      messageNumberArray = messageNumberArray + msgs[k].getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + splitKey;
                      messageInformationArray = messageInformationArray + msgs[k].getDisplayMessageBody() + splitKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF you want all inbox message

Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
          Cursor cur = MainActivity.context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
          String sms = "";

          String type = "";

          while (cur.moveToNext()) 

          {

              int t = cur.getInt(9);
              if(t == 1 )
              {
                  type = "Inbox";
              }
              else if(t == 2)
              {
                  type = "Send";
              }
              else if(t == 3)
              {
                  type = "Draft";
              }

              Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(cur.getLong(4)));            
              SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m a");
              String time = timeFormat.format(callDayTime);           
              SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:d");
              String date = dateFormat.format(callDayTime);

              messageTypeArray = messageTypeArray +  type + splitKey;
              messageDateArray = messageDateArray + date + splitKey;
              messageTimeArray = messageTimeArray + time + splitKey;
              messageNumberArray = messageNumberArray + cur.getString(2) + splitKey;
              messageInformationArray = messageInformationArray + cur.getString(12) + splitKey;

              sms += "From :" + cur.getString(2) + "\nMessage :  " + cur.getString(12)+"\nType : " + type + "\nDate : " + date + "\nTime : " + time + "\n---------------\n";         
             // text.setText(sms);


          }
          cur.close();
```